# Connect to Exchange mailbox with Python

Tags: python, email, connection, exchange-server, pywin32

I need to connect to an Exchange mailbox in a Python script, without using any profile setup on the local machine (including using Outlook).  If I use win32com to create a MAPI.Session I could logon (with the Logon() method) with an existing profile, but I want to just provide a username & password.

Is this possible?  If so, could someone provide example code?  I would prefer if it only used the standard library and the pywin32 package.  Unfortunately, enabling IMAP access for the Exchange server (and then using imaplib) is not possible.

In case it is necessary: all the script will be doing is connecting to the mailbox, and running through the messages in the Inbox, retrieving the contents.  I can handle writing the code for that, if I can get a connection in the first place!

To clarify regarding Outlook: Outlook will be installed on the local machine, but it does not have any accounts setup (i.e. all the appropriate libraries will be available, but I need to operate independently from anything setup inside of Outlook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is going to be impossible without using Outlook and a MAPI profile.  If you can sweet talk your mail admin into enabling IMAP on the Exchange server it would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: There is a possiblility you can do what you want with Exchange 2007 using powershell, but I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 149):

I know this is an old thread, but...

If you're using Exchange 2007 or newer, or Office365, take a look at Exchange Web Services. It's a pretty comprehensive SOAP-based interface for Exchange, and you can do pretty much anything Outlook is able to do, including delegate or impersonation access to other user accounts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/ews-reference-for-exchange

UPDATE: I have released a [Python EWS client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib/) on PyPI that supports autodiscover, calendars, inbox, tasks, contacts, and more:

```py
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials

credentials = Credentials(
    username='MYDOMAIN\\myusername',  # Or me@example.com for O365
    password='topsecret'
)
a = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='john@example.com', 
    credentials=credentials, 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE
)
# Print first 100 inbox messages in reverse order
for item in a.inbox.all().only('subject').order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    print(item.subject)
```

Comment: +1 as this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is there a python wrapper library that implements that?

Comment: Is this EWS client available in Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, it supports both Python 2 and 3

Comment: Your library and the sample code that you provided worked flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: Does this support proxies @ErikCederstrand ? Cant figure out how to use through proxy

Comment: I must admit I have very little understanding of proxies in an EWS context. Usually, your autodiscover server will just hand out a URL to an EWS endpoint for the account to use. That URL will hide whatever complexity you have internally.

Comment: I have difficulties with the credentials for Office 365. I mainly want to read my emails. So I know my email address and my password. What is `MYWINDOMAIN`?  What is the difference between `Credentials` and `ServiceAccount`? Do they have the same username / password?

Comment: For Office365, the username is always the primary SMTP address, AFAIK. So, no WINDOMAIN. Re `ServiceAccount`, it's the same as `Credentials` except it implements some automatic backoff policies when the server is failing.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems Exchange Web Services is a thing that needs to be enabled by the server administrator.  exchangelib did not let me log in to an Exchange server which was set to use only the MAPI protocol: it just said requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: This is awesome! This is a potential game-changer for an IBM i shop like ours!

Comment: Amazing, still working. How do you download the attachment?

Comment: That’s described in the “Attachments” section of the README.

Comment: This is the way thank you

Answer (score 31):

Ive got it, to connect to outbound exchange you need to connect like this:

```
import smtplib

url = YOUR_EXCHANGE_SERVER
conn = smtplib.SMTP(url,587)
conn.starttls()
user,password = (EXCHANGE_USER,EXCHANGE_PASSWORD)
conn.login(user,password)
```

now you can send like a normal connection

```
message = 'From: FROMADDR\nTo: TOADDRLIST\nSubject: Your subject\n\n{}'
from, to = fromaddr,toaddrs
txt = 'This is my message'
conn.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddrs,msg.format(txt))
```

to get the mail from your inbox its a little different

```
import imaplib

url = YOUR_EXCHANGE_URL
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(url,993)
user,password = (EXCHANGE_USER,EXCHANGE_PASSWORD)
conn.login(user,password)
conn.select('INBOX')
results,data = conn.search(None,'ALL')
msg_ids = data[0]
msg_id_list = msg_ids.split()
```

this gives you a list of message id'
s that you can use to get your emails

```
latest_email_id = msg_id_list[-1]
result,data = conn.fetch(latest_email_id,"(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
```

now raw_email is your email messsage, but its not very pretty, if you want to parse it do somthing like this

```
from email.parser import Parser

p = Parser()
msg = p.parsestr(raw_email)
```

now you can do

```
msg.get('From')
msg.get('Subject')
```

or for the content

```
msg.get_payload()
```

but if its a multipart message your going to need to do a little more processing, luckly a recursive solution is perfect for this situation

```
def process_multipart_message(message):
    rtn = ''
    if message.is_multipart():
        for m in message.get_payload():
            rtn += process_multipart_message(m)
    else:
        rtn += message.get_payload()
    return rtn
```

now

```
msg_contant = process_multipart_message(msg)
```

will give you the whole message every time.

Comment: I need to connect to port 443 and set the security to SSL/TLS (accept all certificates). How would I do that? Have been searching for it but no result so far.

Comment: conn.starttls() before logging in

Comment: If I need to handle a file that is sent to my email using the script - how can I fetch him?
Thanks!!

Comment: This answer does not work if the Exchange server has not been configured to allow IMAP connections.

Comment: With Python 3 the email data needs to be decoded from bytes to string. Remediate with something like: raw_email = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find a way to run the process as that particular user.

[See this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/mstehle/archive/2007/01/03/myth-cdo-1-21-s-session-logon-parameter-profilepassword-actually-does-something.aspx)

I think [pywin32.CreateProcessAsUser](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32process__CreateProcessAsUser_meth.html) is the start of the path you need to go down.  One last edit.  The logged on user handle is obtained from using the [win32security.LogonUser](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32security__LogonUser_meth.html) method