# How can I send an email with an attachment with Python and Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: python, excel, email

Can someone help me send an email from my exchange account and add attachments. SMTP doesnt work, I get immediate timeout issues. 0365 doesn't save a copy to my sent folder. The only other one I know is `exchangelib`

```
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, Message, Mailbox, FileAttachment
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders

email = 'XXXXXXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXXX'

a = Account(email, credentials=Credentials(email, password), autodiscover=True)



dir_path = ('C:/Users/Istcrmt/Documents/Python/PythonforAnaconda3.5/')
excel_name = 'test.xlsx'

#attach an excel file:


for i in email_list.itertuples():
# if you want a copy in the 'Sent' folder
    m = Message(
        account=a 
        ,folder=a.sent
        ,subject=(i.AGENCY_NAME + ' I made an email script.')
        ,body='All bodies are beautiful' 
        ,to_recipients=[Mailbox(email_address=i.NEW_MAIL)])

#attach files
    m.attachments.append(part) 
   # m.attach(cover_letter)

    m.send_and_save()
```

Comment: SMTP should work; are you sure you've made a connection to SMTP?

Comment: Oh no I can't make a connection which is my issue

Comment: I get timeouts even with timeout parameter and or the ssl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how you send emails with an attachment with `exchangelib`:

```
from exchangelib import ServiceAccount, Configuration, Account, DELEGATE
from exchangelib import Message, Mailbox, FileAttachment

from config import cfg  # load your credentials


def send_email(account, subject, body, recipients, attachments=None):
    """
    Send an email.

    Parameters
    ----------
    account : Account object
    subject : str
    body : str
    recipients : list of str
        Each str is and email adress
    attachments : list of tuples or None
        (filename, binary contents)

    Examples
    --------
    >>> send_email(account, 'Subject line', 'Hello!', ['info@example.com'])
    """
    to_recipients = []
    for recipient in recipients:
        to_recipients.append(Mailbox(email_address=recipient))
    # Create message
    m = Message(account=account,
                folder=account.sent,
                subject=subject,
                body=body,
                to_recipients=to_recipients)

    # attach files
    for attachment_name, attachment_content in attachments or []:
        file = FileAttachment(name=attachment_name, content=attachment_content)
        m.attach(file)
    m.send_and_save()


credentials = ServiceAccount(username=cfg['user'],
                             password=cfg['password'])

config = Configuration(server=cfg['server'], credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=cfg['smtp_address'], config=config,
                  autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

# Read attachment
attachments = []
with open('filestorage/numbers-test-document.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
attachments.append(('whatever.pdf', content))

# Send email
send_email(account, 'Test 14:35', 'works', ['info@example.com'],
           attachments=attachments)
```

Related: [Read emails and download attachment from an Exchange Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438174/562769)

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for me. Account object is throwing error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
exchangelib.errors.AutoDiscoverFailed: All steps in the autodiscover protocol failed

Comment: You may have autodiscover turned off for your account by your admin. You can test autodiscover at https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com using the outlook connectivity test.