# Access a Microsoft Exchange account via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I'm looking to access Microsoft exchange account via python.

1. Access the mail
2. Read the inbox
3. Without using smtp.

Any suggestions on how it can be done

Comment: Maybe this clould help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/288546/8765205

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Exchange mailbox with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288546/connect-to-exchange-mailbox-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

This module provides an well-performing, well-behaving, platform-independent and simple interface for communicating with a Microsoft Exchange 2007-2016 Server or Office365 using Exchange Web Services (EWS). It currently implements autodiscover, and functions for searching, creating, updating, deleting, exporting and uploading calendar, mailbox, task, contact and distribution list items.

https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/